# Button Press Event Takes Long Time To Reach Handler

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have a `webform` project, and have a page that has about 15 `asp:Button`  on it and a DataGrid that loads data on `Page_Load()`  The `Page_Load()` time is < 5 seconds, but when a button on the page is pressed it's as if the page freezes and nothing happens!  I have waited for 5 minutes for my breakpoint to be hit and it never hits.  What could be bogging down my page?  Here is a snippet showing my set-up, can someone help determine the means to expedite this?

I have a breakpoint set on `MakeAMove("Posties");` that never gets hit...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="1234.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pages.1234" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div class="BlankRowThinWhite">
</div>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="White">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" class="White">
            <asp:Button ID="btnMaster" runat="server" Text="Do Something" OnClick="btnMaster_Click" CssClass="Buttons" />
            --More buttons here
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblOutcome" runat="server" CssClass="BoldTextBlack"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" class="White">
            <asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="dgblahblah" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="DataGrids" GridLines="Both" ShowFooter="true">
                <ItemStyle CssClass="row" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="abc" HeaderText="abc" />
                    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="12" HeaderText="12" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:DataGrid>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
</asp:Content>


protected void btnMaster_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  MakeAMove("Posties"); 
}
```

**EDIT**
It seems my lag time is stemming from my `Page_Load()` event being fired multiple times after a button press. Below is code for my `C#` code behind.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
  if (!IsPostBack) 
  {   
    PopulateDG();
  }
}   

private void PopulateDG()
{
  DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
  using (var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("GetInfo", con))
  using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
  {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    da.Fill(dt1);
  }
  PopulateDG.DataSource = dt1;
  PopulateDG.DataBind();
}  

protected void btnMaster_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   MakeAMove("Posties"); 
}

private void MakeAMove(string info)
{
  //More Data Here
}
```

Comment: Did you try removing the 14 other buttons and make the test with a single one? And also removing the AjaxControlToolkit (if you can afford it for a test), to simplify things.

Comment: @ConnorsFan - removing the extra buttons made no change, but removing the AJAX line made the breakpoint be hit instantly.  What exactly does the AJAXControlToolkit enable that I would need on this page?

Comment: The AjaxControlToolkit makes available some controls that use the AJAX technology. I don't see any of them in your markup. If you don't need it, you can remove the line from your markup.

Comment: I have removed the Ajax line permanently but it is now back to a slow (roughly 60 - 120 seconds) time before the breakpoint is hit from button press.

Comment: So, the same code as in your previous comment now behaves differently?

Comment: Unfortunately so.  And this is on my local machine, and I just did a reboot to see if something was hung-up with the IIS instance for Visual Studio debug.

Comment: If you put an additional breakpoint in the Page_Load event, is it hit much quicker than the one in your button handler?

Comment: Page_Load() is hit instantly, but when I press a button the event handler for the corresponding button takes lengthy time to be reached.  (not sure what takes place in the meantime between a button press and C# being hit)

Comment: Just to be sure, I was talking about Page_Load being hit after clicking the button. In other words, in the same postback, is there a delay between the Page_Load handler and the button handler? If so (maybe that's what you said), then some processing is going on in your code between the two.

Comment: My mistake, I thought you meant the initial page load.  Page_load is hit insstantly, but  my if (!IsPostBack) line being hit repeatedly, which is peculiar as nothing should be executing once the page loads, right?

Comment: The Page_Load event is triggered on every postback, not only the first time the page loads. The processing that needs to be done only on the initial page load is put inside a `if (!IsPostBack)` condition (`IsPostBack` is true for the calls after the initial one). The rest of the handler is executed every time.

Comment: So it is normal that my code jumps to the Page_Load() event multiple times before actually going to the button press event that I am wanting it to go to?

Comment: On a given postback, Page_Load should be called only once (as far as I know). If it is called multiple times, can you see the call stack when your breakpoint is hit again?

Comment: What is in site.master?

Comment: @MaCron - a header & menu bar that is displayed on all pages.  This is the only page experiencing any sort of bottleneck.